# Check the correctness of the creation of beans

Tags: java, spring

Good afternoon!
Tell me, please, is such an implementation possible?
The task is to create two bins of classes A and T. Then they are used inside the project. You also need to create other beans "EAspect", "AAspect", "QAspect", and embed already created beans in them (otherwise autowired does not work inside them).
Everything works, but we need comments on the best implementation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    A a;

    @Autowired
    T t;

    @Bean
    public EAspect getEAspect(@Autowired A a) {
        EAspect eAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(EAspect.class);
        eAspect.setA(a, t);
        return eAspect;
    }

    @Bean
    public AAspect getAAspect(@Autowired A a) {
        AAspect aAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(AAspect.class);
        aAspect.setA(a, t);
        return aAspect;
    }

    @Bean
    public QAspect getQAspect(@Autowired A a) {
        QAspect qAspect = Aspects.aspectOf(QAspect.class);
        qAspect.setA(a, t);
        return qAspect;
    }

    @Bean
    public T getT() {
        T t = new T();
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(a) && a.status)
            t.setBeginningCollection(LocalDateTime.now());
        return t;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you no need to inject `A` and `T` into configuration, just put it into target bean methods, Spring automatically try to inject it into. Like

    @Bean
    public T getT(A a) {...}

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this code, and the result is that when the bean is loaded, it will not try to reload the bean object that has not been loaded in your method, so maybe It's a bit of a mouthful, but I reproduced your code and got this error:

```
Field a in *.*.*.config.AppConfig required a bean of type '*.*.*.*.A' that could not be found.
```

So I drew this picture, I hope you can help you enough!

```html
<br/>
<div align=center><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/14KIF.png"></div>
```

[image]